# Failed importing Tesseract library to Angular 7

Tags: angular

I try to import the "Tesseract" library inside my angular app.
I did those steps:

```
npm install tesseract.js --save
npm install @types/tesseract.js --save-dev
```

Inside my service i importing like this:

```
import * as Tesseract from 'tesseract.js';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()

    export class OcrService {
            setNewImage(file) {     
                Tesseract.recognize(file)
                    .then(function (result) {
                        console.log(result)
                })
            }
        }
```

but I got the next error message when trying to run `setNewImage()`:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 'http://localhost:4200/dist/worker.dev.js?nocache=u87pdjkghm' failed to load.
    at blob:http://localhost:4200/23b6850f-cb9c-4673-a078-111b85405997:1:1
```

Comment: @MaihanNijat You mean in the app module ?

Answer (score 0):

This issue should be fixed in the tesseract.js@1.0.16, please install and check if the issue is resolved.

Thanks for supporting this library, right now I am working on the tesseract.js@2, which should be released in near future, thanks.